# Error code 1. Cordova Visual 2015 Studio

Tags: android, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I was usually running my application, however was not getting access in the emulator due to the network proxy, I made some changes in the emulator network to gain access, however now when I run the application I'm having the following error:

[image]

I have tried clearing the cordova cache several times however not decided.
Also I tried to delete the specific way, however also not decided, what should I do with this error.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear about your trouble. There are a couple of things that could be causing this. One possibility is that you need the 64-bit JDK because you are running into issues. However, it looks like you're more likely missing a dependency.

Can you try running the dependency checker and verify that you're not missing anything? Go to tools -> options -> Tools for Apache Cordova -> Run Dependency Checker and install anything that it says you're missing.

Comment: Was working fine, I debuguei several times however the application has stopped working. The following photo of dependencies. http://imgur.com/7b0E7KV